# what dose this generic function do?

Tags: java, list, generics, syntax

I have a `Class` to create an `ImmutableList` using **generics** and **recursion** to improve performance which have a method that I'm not able to understand :

```
public <E2> ImmutableList<E2> transform(Function<? super E, ? extends E2> fn) {
        return tail == null
            ? new ImmutableList<E2>()
            : new ImmutableList<E2>(fn.apply(head), tail.transform(fn));
    }
```

this syntax is new to me what dose the `<E2>` that comes after `public` for ? 
and what dose this parameter means ? `Function<? super E, ? extends E2> fn`

here is the hole class :

```
public final class ImmutableList<E> {

    public final E head;
    public final ImmutableList<E> tail;

    public ImmutableList() {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
    }

    private ImmutableList(E head, ImmutableList<E> tail) {
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
    }

    public ImmutableList<E> prepend(E element) {
        return new ImmutableList<E>(element, this);
    }

    public <E2> ImmutableList<E2> transform(Function<? super E, ? extends E2> fn) {
        return tail == null
            ? new ImmutableList<E2>()
            : new ImmutableList<E2>(fn.apply(head), tail.transform(fn));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((head == null) ? 0 : head.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((tail == null) ? 0 : tail.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof ImmutableList))
            return false;
        ImmutableList other = (ImmutableList) obj;
        if (head == null) {
            if (other.head != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!head.equals(other.head))
            return false;
        if (tail == null) {
            if (other.tail != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!tail.equals(other.tail))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

and this is the function interface :

```
public interface Function<A, B> {
    B apply(A value);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`transform` accepts a `Function` from `E` to `E2` (or, to be more exact, from `E` or a super-type of `E` to `E2` or a sub-type of `E2`). `Function` is an interface with a single method called `apply()`. `fn.apply()` accepts a parameter of type `E` and returns a parameter of type `E2`.

`transform` applies the function on all the elements of the list on which it is executed, so it generates an `ImmutableList<E2>` from the input `ImmutableList<E>` on which it was executed.

`<E2>` is a generic type parameter that represents the type of the element contained in the list returned by the `transform` method.